# Timer is not stopping

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm creating a basic game and my timer is not stopping. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Timer04_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer04.Tick
    ProgressBar4.Increment(9)
    If ProgressBar4.Value = 100 Then
        Timer04.Stop()
        MsgBox("100%")
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me stop the timer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timer is not stopping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572930/timer-is-not-stopping)

Comment: Is this Windows Forms?

Comment: Yes, this is a Windows Forms application.

Comment: @ONT - You need a [mcve] at the point. Please read that link and let me know if you have any questions about how to change your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost certainly that your `ProgressBar` value never equals 100. You can determine this for yourself by logging its value each time you go into the `Tick` event. However, I would simply change this line:

```
   If ProgressBar4.Value = 100 Then
```

to this:

```
   If ProgressBar4.Value >= 100 Then
```

That should solve the problem.

**Edit:** Even if it does solve the problem, it isn't the best way to handle it.

You should take Enigmativity's advice and evaluate `ProgressBar.Maximum` instead of checking to see if the value is 100. Now, the default maximum value is 100, and default minimum value is 0. So, if you keep incrementing by 9, you'll get to 99 after 11 calls to the `Increment` method. Now, the doc ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.increment?view=netframework-4.7.2)} says this:

> If, after calling the Increment method, the Value property is greater than the value of the Maximum property, the Value property remains at the value of the Maximum property.

So, if you're at 99, incrementing one more time will get you to 100 if you haven't changed the maximum.

Since you never seem to get to 100, you've probably changed the `Maximum` property somewhere so that the `Value` property never equals 100, as Enigmativity suggests.

Comment: All right. So you need to log the `Value` property to the Console (use `Console.WriteLine`) right after you call `Increment`, and see what you get.

Comment: Try adding `Console.WriteLine(ProgressBar4.Value)` as a new line immediately after the line where you increment it by 9. Then look in your debug\immediate window to see the output.

Comment: @ONT After two copies of "sorry, but this doesn't work either" and your request to be given the exact line of code, I have this to say. It was nice of CResults to give you that full line of code, but if I may say so without giving offense, you might have attempted to figure the line of code out for yourself before asking for help. I suggest that you get back into the mindset of being an active participant in solving your problem, rather than asking to be led by the nose to the solution. Your active participation will help you solve your problem more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this:

```
Private Sub Timer04_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer04.Tick
    ProgressBar4.Increment(9)
    If ProgressBar4.Value = ProgressBar4.Maximum Then
        Timer04.Stop()
        MsgBox("100%")
    End If
End Sub
```

I suspect somewhere else in your code you have set `ProgressBar4.Maximum` to something other than `100`.

The bottom-line on this is don't use "magic numbers" like `100`. Always use a variable or constant.

Comment: Better answer than mine.

Comment: If you change `If ProgressBar4.Value = ProgressBar4.Maximum` to `If ProgressBar4.Value => ProgressBar4.Maximum` does the code then work? Do you know what `ProgressBar4.Maximum` is set to?

Comment: @CResults Being a bit dyslexic, I looked it up, just to be sure. The "greater than or equal to" operator is `>=` rather than `=>`. (Darn those lambda expressions.) We don't want the OP to try your line, and say "sorry, it doesn't work" again, with no further information. :)

Comment: @ONT - I tested the code before I posted on a progress bar. This code works if the value hits or or exceeds `ProgressBar4.Maximum`. There's no need for `>=` as the control stops incrementing once it hits the maximum value. At this point you need to provide a [mcve] for any further help.

Comment: @CResults - The control doesn't increment past the maximum value so there's no need for `>=`.

Comment: I'd had a drink. I'll gracefully stand back!